# Updating message of existing notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I made a class dedicated for starting a notification from the service to make it a foreground service. Now, I would like to periodically update message displayed on the notification without raising any alert (like sound). How could I do it?

```
class ForegroundServiceNotification
{
    private String CHANNEL_ID;
    private Service service;

    ForegroundServiceNotification(Service service)
    {
        this.service = service;

        setupChannel();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(service, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(service, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Some initial title")
            .setContentText("Some initial text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

        service.startForeground(1, notification);
    }

    private void setupChannel()
    {
        CHANNEL_ID = service.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            return;

        NotificationManager manager = service.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (manager == null)
            return;

        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        serviceChannel.setSound(null, null);
        serviceChannel.enableVibration(false);
        serviceChannel.setShowBadge(false);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }

    public void update(String title, String text)
    {
        // HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT IT?
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a complete solution. Below example works even if user closed existing notification. Also Android O is supported.

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

class ForegroundServiceNotification
{
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 11794;
    private String CHANNEL_ID;
    private Service service;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    ForegroundServiceNotification(Service service)
    {
        this.service = service;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        setupChannel();

        update("Some title", "Some text");
    }

    void update(String title, String text)
    {
        boolean isNotificationVisible = false;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && notificationManager != null) {

            StatusBarNotification[] notifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
            for (StatusBarNotification notification : notifications)
                if (notification.getId() == NOTIFICATION_ID) {
                    isNotificationVisible = true;
                    break;
                }
        }

        Notification notification = buildNotification(title, text);
        if (isNotificationVisible)
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        else
            service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void setupChannel()
    {
        CHANNEL_ID = service.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O || notificationManager == null)
            return;

        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        serviceChannel.setSound(null, null);
        serviceChannel.enableVibration(false);
        serviceChannel.setShowBadge(false);
        serviceChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }

    private Notification buildNotification(String title, String text)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(service.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            service, 0, intent, 0);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            return new Notification.Builder(service, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(service, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();
    }
}
```